# No Source Available while debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, aspdotnetstorefront

[image: a](![Debug Error Window])

I copied a website from one Computer to another Computer. Everything works fine but i am not able to debug it.

The description of image says that Looking in a script documents for

```
      'D:\Projects\Golden Plaza\ASODNSFCore\AppLogic.cs''
```

This location is not there in my computer not the one from which I copied it.

It is a ASPDOTNETSTOREFRONT website.

Comment: Not sure if i'm reading you right, are you saying 'D:\Projects\Golden Plaza\ASODNSFCore\AppLogic.cs'' isn't on the computer you copied this from either?

Comment: Do you have the source code for `AppLogic.cs` located anywhere on your computer?

Comment: @cost yes.. The computer from where I copied does not have this location.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No.. I tried searching in the location from where I copied also doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if its a typo but you have the directory as ASODNSF rather than ASPDNSF in your path.

The applogic.cs file certainly does live in the ASPDNSFCore files. Make sure that you have copied the parent folder over instead of just the root (Web) folder. This, along with the other source code files, are in the directory above.

If that still fails then login to your account at Vortx (AspDotNetStoreFront's site) and download the full source files and copy them over. The source code files that live in the parent directory are really just for reference as rebuilding the library will amend the dll files that sit within the root (web) folder.

And obviously make sure that the bindings within IIS on the machine you copied it to also point to the correct path.